# Java eclipse can't disabled new menu options

Tags: java

I use eclipse, I have aproblem that when I click on the file -> new menu, all the options are greyed. I am clicking on my current project. But I guess this problem happened after deleting a project from the file system not from the eclipse (possibly not sure). How can I solve the problem ?

**EDIT:** The message I get:

> No Applicable items

Answer (score 0):

You can change workspace:

left click on the project, export, file system --> choose another folder
then Eclipse menu File, Switch Workspace --> choose the previous selected folder

if this is not working you can always save your project and delete eclipse, download it and unzip it, is gonna work just fine

keep always a bopy of Eclipse in a local folder so you can replace it while you keep doing messy things ;) don't delete folders from the file system, just delete them from the eclipse and if you delete a full project check the option "delete files from file system"

but with the hd you have today, really do you need to delete anything?